# does "natural" here means that people use of that expressions regularly?

Tags: meaning, word-meaning

does "natural" here means that those people use of that expressions regularly?

> Idiomatic language uses words in a way that sounds **natural** to native
>    speakers of the language.
>
> idiomatic means: using, containing, or denoting expressions that are **natural** to a
>   native speaker.

Comment: It refers to the way in which a native speaker would be most likely to express that idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The notion of natural language is difficult. All language is learnt, so nobody is a natural English speaker.

However there are some phrases which, while they seem to be grammatically correct are not often used. Sometimes it can be hard, even for a native speaker, to say why.

An example is the ordering of adjectives:

> It is a big round wooden bowl.
>
> It is a wooden round big bowl
>
> It is big a bowl round wooden.

The first is grammatical and natural.

The second has the same grammar, but is unnatural. Size and shape adjectives tend to precede the material. A native speaker would understand this, but it sounds odd.

The third is ungrammatical.

But native speakers don't often say "It is a big round wooden bowl" (unless you make or sell bowls). Yet there is something natural about this first example that the second is lacking.

So "natural" is the way that a native speaker would express a concept.